# On the common zeros of $1-x\tan{x}$ and $1-\frac1x \arctan{\frac1x}$

Tags: real-analysis

This is ON HOLD on [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/215514/on-the-common-zeros-of-1-x-tanx-and-1-1-x-arctan1-x).

Let $f(x)=1-x\tan{x}$.

Let $g(x)=1-\frac1x \arctan{\frac1x}$.

Let $r=0.8603335890193797624838\ldots$ be a real root of $f(x)=0$.

High precision numerical computations suggest $f(\pm r)=g(\pm r)=0$.

$g(x)$ doesn't appear to have other complex roots (might be
wrong about this).

> Q1 Is it true $f(\pm r)=g(\pm r)=0$?
>
> Q2 If this is true, is there closed form for $r$ in terms of already
> named functions and constants?

On MO commenter wrote "This is just arctan(tan(x))=x" but I don't understand this.

Xray (vanishing of the real and imaginary parts of f(x) and g(x) in the complex plane), common zero is where all four curves intersect:

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BmA4Z.png):

[image]

Comment: Aren't they the same equation? For $\frac{1}{x} \arctan(\frac{1}{x}) = 1$ if and only if $x = \arctan(\frac{1}{x})$ if and only if $\tan(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ if and only if $x\tan(x) = 1$.

Comment: @GeoffRobinson Thanks, will check this. Modulo my errors this contradicts the plot, do you have other zero, taking any branch?

Comment: Well, I was thinking of $\arctan$ as a single-valued function above..

Comment: @GeoffRobinson The plot takes the principal branch. For the root of f(x)=0:  r=6.43729817917195..., g(r) doesn't vanish for me or am I missing something?

Comment: it vanishes for some other branch of arctan.

Comment: @mercio Indeed, thank you.